# Type-hinting for the __init__ function from class meta information in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, type-hinting

What I'd like to do is replicate what `SQLAlchemy` does, with its `DeclarativeMeta` class.  With this code,

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
```

When you go to create a person in `PyCharm`, `Person(...`, you get typing hints about `id: int, name: str, age: int`,

[image: Type-hinting with Python, PyCharm and SQLAlchemy]

How it works at runtime is via the SQLAlchemy's `_declarative_constructor` functions,

```
def _declarative_constructor(self, **kwargs):
    cls_ = type(self)
    for k in kwargs:
        if not hasattr(cls_, k):
            raise TypeError(
                "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" %
                (k, cls_.__name__))
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
_declarative_constructor.__name__ = '__init__'
```

And to get the *really* nice type-hinting (where if your class has a id field, `Column(Integer)` your constructor type-hints it as `id: int`), `PyCharm` is actually doing some under-the-hood magic, specific to SQLAlchemy, but I don't need it to be that good / nice, I'd just like to be able to programatically add type-hinting, from the meta information of the class.

So, in a nutshell, if I have a class like,

```
class Simple:
    id: int = 0

    name: str = ''
    age: int = 0
```

I want to be able to init the class like above, `Simple(id=1, name='asdf')`, but also get the type-hinting along with it.  I can get halfway (the functionality), but not the type-hinting.

If I set things up like SQLAlchemy does it,

```
class SimpleMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)


metaclass = SimpleMeta(
    'Meta', (object,), dict(__init__=_declarative_constructor))


class Simple(metaclass):
    id: int = 0

    name: str = ''
    age: int = 0


print('cls', typing.get_type_hints(Simple))
print('init before', typing.get_type_hints(Simple.__init__))
Simple.__init__.__annotations__.update(Simple.__annotations__)
print('init after ', typing.get_type_hints(Simple.__init__))
s = Simple(id=1, name='asdf')
print(s.id, s.name)
```

It *works*, but I get no type hinting,

[image: No __init__ type hint]

And if I do pass parameters, I actually get an `Unexpected Argument` warning,

[image: Unexpected Argument]

In the code, I've *manually* updated the `__annotations__`, which makes the `get_type_hints` return the correct thing,

```
cls {'id': <class 'int'>, 'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>}
init before {}
init after  {'id': <class 'int'>, 'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>}
1 asdf
```

Comment: Consider using `dataclasses` introduced in Py3.7 stdlib and available for Py3.6 as a package or `attrs` library. Namedtuples also could be useful.

Comment: Pycharm doesn't have great support (at least in terms of auto completion and type hinting) for other libraries like sqlalchemy and pydantic at the moment, unfortunately. Though it does have great support for builtin libraries like dataclasses as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python 3.7 above, you can achieve same effect by using `@dataclass` and adding appropriate typehint to the instance fields.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

[image: screenshot of typehint]

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `__annotations__` from `__init__` is the correct way to go there. It is possible to do so using a metaclass, classdecorator, or an appropriate `__init_subclass__` method on your base classes.

However, PyCharm raising this warning should be treated as a bug in Pycharm itself: Python has documented mechanisms in the language so that `object.__new__` will ignore extra arguments on a class instantiation (which is a "class call") if an `__init__` is defined in any subclass in the inheritance chain.  On yielding this warning, pycharm is actually behaving differently than the language spec.

The work around it is to have the same mechanism that updates `__init__` to create a proxy `__new__` method with the same signature. However, this method will have to swallow any args itself  - so getting the correct behavior if your class hierarchy needs an actual `__new__` method somewhere is a complicating edge case.

The version with `__init_subclass__` would be more or less:

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        if not "__init__" in cls.__dict__:
            cls.__init__ = lambda self, *args, **kw: super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        cls.__init__.__annotations__.update(cls.__annotations__)
        if "__new__" not in cls.__dict__:
            cls.__new__ = lambda cls, *args, **kw: super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)
                cls.__new__.__annotations__.update(cls.__annotations__)
```

Python correctly updates a class' `.__annotations__` attribute upon inheritance, therefore even this simple code works with inheritance (and multiple inheritance) - the `__init__` and `__new__` methods are always set with the correct annotations even for attributes defined in superclasses.

Comment: Just tried this by redefining `class Simple(Base):`, but in `__init_subclass__`, without changing `Simple`, there is no `"__init__"` key in `cls.__dict__`, so the rest of your code doesn't run.

Comment: Just change the  `if` condition to create an empty `__init__` then. It should be trivial .